# Implementation of MVC in a Java Swing app

Tags: java, mvc, swing

I am planning to create a POS swing application (personal project) for small scale businesses in my local town. I just want to know if this is the right way of implementing MVC in a swing app (I have no professional experience in creating swing apps). This is my initial implementation for the app (Login) starting from domain to view.

Domain:

```
public class Account extends AbstractDomain {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Repository (Initial implementation. Planning to use HSQL and Hibernate):

```
public class AccountRepository {

    private Map<String, Account> accountMap;

    public AccountRepository() {

        accountMap = new HashMap<String, Account>();

        Account account1 = new Account();

        account1.setId(1L);
        account1.setUsername("jeromepogi");
        account1.setPassword("password");

        Account account2 = new Account();

        account2.setId(2L);
        account2.setUsername("pogijerome");
        account2.setPassword("password");

        Account account3 = new Account();

        account3.setId(3L);
        account3.setUsername("jeromepogi123");
        account3.setPassword("password");

        accountMap.put(account1.getUsername(), account1);
        accountMap.put(account2.getUsername(), account2);
        accountMap.put(account3.getUsername(), account3);
    }

    public Account findByUsername(String username) {
        return accountMap.get(username);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class AccountService {

    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountService() {

        //planning to use spring for dependencies
        accountRepository = new AccountRepository();
    }

    public Account login(String username, String password) throws LoginException{

        Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(account == null || !account.getPassword().equals(password)){
            throw new LoginException();
        }

        return account;
    }
}
```

View:

```
public class LoginView extends JFrame {

    private JLabel lblUsername;

    private JLabel lblPassword;

    private JTextField txtUsername;

    private JPasswordField txtPassword;

    private JButton btnLogin;

    private JButton btnExit;

    public LoginView(){

        initFrame();
        initComponents();
        setUpView();
    }

    public void initFrame(){
        setTitle("POS");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void initComponents(){
        lblUsername = new JLabel("Username: ");
        lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");

        lblUsername.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 20));

        txtUsername = new JTextField(15);
        txtPassword = new JPasswordField(20);

        txtUsername.setFont(new Font(null, 0, 20));
        txtPassword.setFont(new Font(null, 0 ,20));

        btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");

        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnLogin);
    }

    public void setUpView(){

        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        InnerPanel innerPanel = new InnerPanel();

        innerPanel.add(lblUsername);
        innerPanel.add(txtUsername);
        innerPanel.add(lblPassword);
        innerPanel.add(txtPassword);
        innerPanel.add(btnLogin);
        innerPanel.add(btnExit);

        mainPanel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(mainPanel);
    }

    public void showView(){

        setVisible(true);
    } 

    public void exit(){
        dispose();
    }

    public JTextField getTxtUsername() {
        return txtUsername;
    }

    public JPasswordField getTxtPassword() {
        return txtPassword;
    }

    public JButton getBtnLogin() {
        return btnLogin;
    }

    public JButton getBtnExit() {
        return btnExit;
    }

    private class MainPanel extends JPanel{

        public MainPanel(){

            super(new BorderLayout());
            setUp();
        }

        private void setUp(){

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        }
    }

    private class InnerPanel extends JPanel{

        public InnerPanel(){

            super(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            setUp();
        }

        private void setUp(){

            TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK), "Login");
            border.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10,10)));
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class LoginController {

    private LoginView loginView;

    private AccountService accountService;

    public LoginController() {

        loginView = new LoginView();
        accountService = new AccountService();
        setActionListeners();
    }

    public void start(){
        loginView.showView();
    }

    public void login(){

        try {

            String username = loginView.getTxtUsername().getText();
            String password = String.valueOf(loginView.getTxtPassword().getPassword());

            accountService.login(username, password);

            // To main frame
        } catch (LoginException e) {

            // Show error dialog  
        }
    }

    public void setActionListeners(){

        loginView.getBtnLogin().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                login();
            }
        });

        loginView.getBtnExit().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loginView.exit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final LoginController loginController = new LoginController();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                loginController.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So this is my initial implementation of the app. I just want to know if I am in the right path.

Comment: I assume it's currently working as intended?

Comment: Yes sir. It is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This review is basically split into two parts. The first one is a really bad (and unfortunately pretty personal) beating, the second is a bit more differentiated.

I would really feel like a broken record, but hey ... It's high time I reviewed some outdated, EOL'd technology with the same beginner (and tutorial) mistakes made again ... Or maybe I don't.
Just read the first section of this [answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/157176/37660), if you're interested in what I have to say on the choice of technology.

Of special note: You don't do the "`setVisible(true);` in the constructor" that I dislike so much, which is great.

What you do do is being annoyingly abstract. Just for one small login view, you have **5** classes, where 3 are sufficient. I guess what's bothering me most is the use of `Service` and `Repository` and `AbstractDomain`.

You specifically state that you're intending to use HSQL and Hibernate to interact with a database. This automatically makes both your Service and Repository superfluous, the moment you use the proper tools bundled with those two. Consider the following:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Account {

    @NotNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @Size(min = 5, max = 12)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;
}
```

This is hibernate validation constraints with Lombok's `@Data`, because I'm too lazy to type out the getters.

If we now wanted to retrieve users by their username, we can use the `EntityManager` as follows:

```
Account acc = EntityManager.find<Account>(Account.class, username);
if (acc == null) { /* account does not exist */
    // hash & compare the password anyways to prevent timing attacks
    throw new LoginException();
}
// well, we're basically logged in here...
```

This code accomplishes **all** the things that happen in `AccountRepository` and `AccountService`, just in a very likely correct way, with caching and other really fancy stuff, written by people smarter than you and me.

Which reminds me ... You have a username and a password. Just to be on the safe side, you want to get the password stored in a way that makes it basically impossible for you (or anyone else that might steal the data in your database) to guess the actual password. This means you should use a proper secure hashing algorithm (Blowfish, BCRYPT, SCRYPT, ...<sup>[1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/157176/37660)</sup>) and a one-time hash.

#### `</beating>`

On to greener pastures or something:

- Again: good job on not falling into the trap of `setVisible(true);` in the constructor.
- Good use of composition and separated responsibilities in the View with `initFrame`, `initComponents` and `setUpView`. I'd have preferred to see this go one step further, though. Instead of `extends JFrame`, it's generally more modern to have an instance-field, to properly encapsulate interactions with the GUI and keep the exposed interface as small as possible. (This also applies to `MainPanel` and `InnerPanel` btw.)
- The names are chosen pretty nicely, except for the component names in the View, where a **lot** of systems hungarian is used. Prefixing variables (and fields) with their type in the name (`lbl`, `btn`, `txt`,…) is tempting, but it shouldn't be done. There's no reason to not trust in your IDE to be able to tell you the type of a variable.
- MVC is properly implemented, thumbs up
- There is a few missed opportunities where Lambda-Expressions could be used (especially with `invokeLater` and `addActionListener`)

<sup>[1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/157176/37660)</sup> Advice on algorithms is probably out of date... research the state-of-the-art algorithms, please.